# How to write "Order By" clause before "Where" clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write an `ORDER BY` clause before my `WHERE` condition because I need to truncate my results to just 10, but I need to sort them in alphabetical order first.

I know that you can't put `ORDER BY` before `WHERE` so how can I do it?

I need to do something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY TOP10
WHERE ROWNUM <=10
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it the other way around? Or just *assumed* that it doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: @MatBailie Yep.  Tried it.  Didn't work.  It's giving me ten results, but they are only sorted according to the ten truncated records.

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY TOP10 LIMIT 10` ? (Doesn't work in Oracle I guess?)

Comment: @agbinfo Yeah, isn't working for me...

Comment: Note that in mariadb, order by inside subqueries will not be respected https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use an inline view for this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT *
 FROM myTable
 ORDER BY TOP10) T
WHERE ROWNUM <=10
```

Comment: +1. An explanation is in Tom Kyte's "Ask Tom" column from September 2006, ["On ROWNUM and Limiting Results"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html). Note that Oracle handles this query intelligently; in particular, it *won't* try to sort the entire table and then select the top ten rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TOP10) rank) 
WHERE rank <= 10;
```

For more see [this](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_select_the_top_n_rows_from_a_table)

Edited: Thanks Wolf for correction:

```
select * from (select mt.*, rank() over (order by top10) rank from mytable mt) 
WHERE rank <= 10
```

Comment: Are there any benefits to this over an inline view?

Comment: You are using an analytic function directly after the table name? This does not appear to be syntactically correct. You can add a column to the inline view using the `rank()` analytic function, but not as written. You probably meant something like this: `select * from (select mt.*, rank() over (order by top10) rank from mytable mt) WHERE rank <= 10;`.