# ORDER before SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which works great

```
$sub_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_status = 'published' AND 
post_user = '{$out}' ORDER BY post_id DESC ";
```

The query brings back all of a specific users posts ordered by descending post id. The problem is it loops through every post user and orders them accordingly but I want the newest post overall not just the newest post per user.

Here is an image of the results to hopefully help explain better
[image: ORDER before SELECT statement]
[image: ORDER before SELECT statement]

[image: ORDER before SELECT statement]
[image: ORDER before SELECT statement]

You can see the query runs for a specific user and then moves on to the next user where I am trying to get the newest post id first

I have tried to follow this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242374/how-to-write-order-by-clause-before-where-clause) but it brought back the same results.

```
$sub_query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC) 
T WHERE post_status = 'published' AND post_user = '{$out}' ";
```

Would I be able to order all of the selected posts first? Then use my where statement?

Comment: The images do little to explain what you want here.  Please edit your question, remove the images, and instead show us sample table data along with your expected output.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: In case you're still not getting the message, remove the images from your question, and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you want the newest post per user, then remove the `where` and add a `limit`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE p.post_status = 'published'
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I still need the WHERE post_user = '{$out}' because those are the specific users

Comment: Yeah put an `AND` then put your `post_user = '{$out}' `.

Comment: @Sand Returns an error mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if what you are looking for is 
1) the list of the last post per user
2) the list of all posts sorted by the newest (regardless the user)
In both case you don't need to loop all users, you can extract data ordered just using the query itself (i strongely advise you on this solution).

option 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(post_id)
    FROM posts 
    WHERE post_status = 'published'
    GROUP BY post_user
)
ORDER BY post_user ASC
```

option 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE post_status = 'published'
post_id DESC
```